# R - filter between date from dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe

my data frame looks like this

```
df <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at  
1            107 2016-12-16 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
3            107 2017-11-28 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
4            109 2016-11-28 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
5            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
6            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

The goal is for each id compare paid_at and date colums and filter only closest date than is between paid_at. For example id 107 it was paid 2017-06-02, and since closest date after that is 2017-11-27, second row should be filtered. Same for id 109, closest date after 2017-01-01 is 2017-11-29 so filter it. Issue for me is situation like id 110, since there is not actually date after 2018-01-01, for this should be filtered 6th row. Result should be

```
result <- read.table(text="
              id date       paid_at    binded_at   
1            107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
2            109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
3            110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07", header=TRUE)
```

I created this code yet:

```
result <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(paid_at > date)
```

Comment: Your `read.table` commands don't work, suggest you remove the `<type>` rows.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to allow `id` which got only one row via `filter` as for those `id`s any condition will not match.

The solution shown by `OP` can be extended to include `id` with only `1` row as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(2:4), as.Date) %>%  #This step is to convert in Date format
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(paid_at < date | n()==1) %>% #Include groups with single row
  arrange(date) %>%
  slice(1)  #Select just 1 row

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
# # Groups: id [3]
#     id    date       paid_at    binded_at 
#   <int>   <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1   107 2017-11-27 2017-06-02 2017-06-07
# 2   109 2017-11-29 2017-01-01 2017-06-07
# 3   110 2017-12-04 2018-01-01 2017-06-07
```

Comment: Thanks, but im getting error - Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Comment: @Jack_Carver May be some of the dates are not in correct format. Are you trying on the sample data or a different data set?

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue, what that n()==1 means please?

Comment: `n()==1` means for that group (`id` in your case) number of record is `1`. `n()` provides number of rows for a group.